# Determine the location of a shared folder in Win7

Tags: finder, windows, script

I am now using Mac OS 10.8, and want to write a script (.sh) to copy some files from Mac to the shared folder of a Win7 computer. I can access the Win7 computer shared folder via Finder, but I do not know the location of the Win7 shared folder when I write the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All shares and removable drives automatically get mounted in `/Volumes/<share path>`.

To show the path of a share in finder you can either right click on the title of the finder window to open a path list leading to the current location.

You can also show the full path in finder by running the following two commands in terminal:

`defaults write com.apple.finder _FXShowPosixPathInTitle -bool YES`
`killall Finder`

Answer (score 1):

In Finder the navigate so that the Win7 folder is the selected one. Then the folder name is in the title of the window and this is the path yo use in your script.

Note you can also use automator and applescript rather than shell scripts.